# Concatenating strings, unevaluated expressions and evaluated expressions/values

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation, hold, expression-construction, concatenation

Maybe this is something very simple to some of you. Anyway, I think this can be useful to many others like me.

I would like to build an output that involves strings, unevaluated expressions and evaluated expressions/values —something like this:

> The value for $C_\mathrm{p}$ is $1.5$ and the value for $\delta^*$ is $0.123$.

where *1.5* and *0.123* are the result of evaluating respective expressions.

This is what I tried:

```
Cp = 1.5; deltastar = 0.123;
HoldForm["The value for " HoldForm[Subscript[C, p]] " is " Evaluate[
   Cp] " and the value for " HoldForm[
   Superscript[\[Delta], "*"]] " is " Evaluate[deltastar] "."]
```

With this result:

[image]

The outer `HoldForm` is necessary to maintain the order of the *pieces*, that are actually considered by Mathematica as being multiplied. For instance, this piece of code:

```
Cp = 1.5; deltastar = 0.123;
"The value for " HoldForm[Subscript[C, p]] " is " Evaluate[
   Cp] " and the value for " HoldForm[
   Superscript[\[Delta], "*"]] " is " Evaluate[deltastar] "."
```

yields to this output:

[image]

Using `ToString` is not an option when there are superscripts and subscripts, as it is the case (I mean, the raw string output is awful). And because of that, I can't use string concatenation , which would be the most natural approach to me.

There should be an easy way to do this in Mathematica, shouldn't there?

As I said, I guess there *actually* is a simple solution for this —that is, **properly building an output text or message that involves strings, unevaluated expressions and evaluated expressions.** Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're merely looking for [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html):

```
Cp = 1.5; deltastar = 0.123;

Row[{
 "The value for ",
 HoldForm[Subscript[C, p]],
 " is ",
 Cp,
 " and the value for ",
 HoldForm[Superscript[\[Delta], "*"]],
 " is ",
 deltastar,
 "."
}]
```

[image]

If this does not work for you please clearly state how it fails so that those issues can be directly addressed.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like `StringForm` can achieve this:

```
Cp = 1.5; deltastar = 0.123;
```

Then:

```
StringForm["The value for `1` is `2` and the value for `3` is `4`.", 
                HoldForm @ Subscript[C, p], Cp, HoldForm @ Superscript[\[Delta], "*"], deltastar]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is worth noting that NumberMarks are displayed with this method. (e.g. "1.5\`")  Using `NumberMarks -> False` does not seem to change this.

Answer (score 3):

In V10 there is a new function [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringTemplate.html) that allows us to build custom formatting functions in a new way. Here is how it can applied to the OP's problem.

```
fmt[args__] := 
  Style[
    StringTemplate[
      "The value for `1` is `2` and the value for `3` is `4`.", 
      CombinerFunction -> Row
      ][args], 
    "SR"]

cpForm = HoldForm@Subscript[C, p]; Cp = 1.5;  
deltaForm =  HoldForm[Superscript[δ, "*"]]; deltastar = 0.123;
fmt[cpForm, Cp, deltaForm, deltastar]
```

> [image: fmt-1]

```
Cp = 1.3; deltastar = 0.42;
fmt[cpForm, Cp, deltaForm, deltastar]
```

> [image: fmt-2]

Note that the [`TemplateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TemplateObject.html) returned by `StringTemplate` acts like a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 1.5;
b = 0.123;

Grid[{{"The value for", RawBoxes[SubscriptBox["c", "p"]], "is", a,
   "and the value for", RawBoxes[SuperscriptBox["\[Delta]", "*"]], "is", b}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but I think `Row` is easier to use an more "canonical" here.